# what is the equivalent of Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1).TableRange1 for working with Power Query Table

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

I have used a Pivot table and using vba

```
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1).TableRange1
```

to select the range and copy the selected range in to an outlook object to be send as an email.

is there an equivalent code to use with power query?

i have limited success with

```
Set rng = Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("mylist").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

as this does not copy column headers

how do i use the same or similar code to use with a power query?
Thanks

Comment: `.ListObjects("mylist").Range`?

Comment: Hi @PatricK Thank you. yes, this would work but my list is filtered, .Rnage copy the whole table but not what visible/filtered

Comment: I was just hinting the Range object instead of DataBodyRange, try `.ListObjects("mylist").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`